# How do you add 2 variables that are numbers to make one variable?

Tags: ruby, vim, cmd

I tried to make a true/false test with GVIM, but when I tried to add all the scores together, it told me "'+' can't convert Fixnum into String". Here's the script:

```
final =(score+score0)
```

How do you add score and score0?

Answer (score 2):

That error is happening because one of those variables is an integer and the other an string.
If you want to add them as a integer you have to convert the string one to int with .to_i

```
final = score.to_i + score0.to_i
```

Comment: Never mind, I figured that out.